# Threads and Graphics

Tags: java, multithreading, graphics

I'm making an applet with a board (like chessboard, size m x n) and every field has to be in a different thread and it has to change color every second until I turn it off. How am I supposed to do this with this? I can't just put `g.setColor` or `g.fillRect` in run method. Is there any way to draw the whole thing and change color every second, all in separate thread for each field, by using `paintComponent` method?

Applet:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class MyApplet extends JApplet {

    public void init() {
        add(new Board(  Integer.parseInt(getParameter("m")),
                            Integer.parseInt(getParameter("n")),
                            Integer.parseInt(getParameter("k")),
                            Integer.parseInt(getParameter("p"))
        ));
    }
}
```

Board:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Random;

class NowyWatek extends Board implements Runnable{
    public NowyWatek(){
        super(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    public void run(){
        Random random=new Random();
        int r1=random.nextInt(255)+0;
        int r2=random.nextInt(255)+0;
        int r3=random.nextInt(255)+0;
        g.setColor(r1, r2, r3);
    }

}

public class Board extends JPanel {
    int m,n,k,p;
    public Board (int m, int n, int k, int p) {
            super();
            this.m = m;
            this.n = n;
            this.k = k;
            this.p = p;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
            int a=0, b=0;
            for(int i=0; i<m*n;i++)
            {
                NowyWatek nowywatek=new NowyWatek();
                Thread thread=new Thread(nowywatek);
                thread.start();
                g.fillRect(a,b,29,29);
                a+=30;
                if(i%n==n-1)
                {
                    a=0;
                    b+=30;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would not recommend creating a new Thread every time paintComponent is called. If you wish to change how a component paints on a regular (and timed) basis, use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), changing the data that needs to be changed and calling `repaint`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it has to change color every second until I turn it off. How am I suppose to do this with this?

1. Create a [swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) that updates the color and calls `repaint` on the Component
2. Keep a reference to a Color object that you change within (1)
3. Pass the Color object from (2) to `g.setColor` in `paintComponent`

For example:

```
Color color = Color.WHITE;
Random random = new Random();
....
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        int r1=random.nextInt(255);
        int r2=random.nextInt(255);
        int r3=random.nextInt(255);
        color = new Color(r1, r2, r3);
        repaint();
    }
});
timer.start();
...
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(color);
    ...
}
```